# Does Wildfly process HTTP requests in order of arrival in a single queue?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

Java web application deployed on wildfly 10. This application exposes Rest webservices.

Users, from different PCs, use a client which interacts with web services.

Packets travel through the network. Several HTTP requests arrive to the Wildfly Server concurrently.

Does Wildfly process HTTP requests in order of arrival in a single queue?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no. That's not really how HTTP requests work anyway. Processing one at a time would be painfully slow and have no way to scale at all.

Comment: So How does wildfly attend http requests?

Comment: That is somewhat of a loaded question. There are several types of HTTP requests that come in. Some use servlet, some use various other endpoint processors. There is no easy answer really.